# Stripping datelines from text

Tags: algorithm, nlp

For example, let's say I have text like this:

```
LOCATION, Text goes on
LOCATION U.S. investigators goes on
LOCATION/LOCATION First Last's goes on
LOCATION (AB) -- The Stack Overflow goes on

WHITE PLAINS, N.Y. (AB) -- Text goes on
PUEBLO, Colo. (AB) -- Text goes on
```

How would I make an algorithm to determine the boundary between the LOCATION and the article text?

The algorithm should be flexible, since there are many formats of datelines in use.

I know this can be done by algorithm, since the boundary is clearly distinguishable even after randomising the chracters.

```
SYAEIDUA, Tuqw gzce ox
QOZHANEPAD G.L. qisuxhen aodien
ADFD/QOIEYTYE Qidne Opaidh's wien aidnen
QIUEHN (XC) -- Ehd Towneyd Apenaid goeis he

IQUEN AOIEND, B.I. (OG) -- Qien oane px
OIQHNED, Qien. (PA) -- Nwne oaien pdxdaf
```

The only confusion I can see is in the second case, where G.L. could either stand for U.S. and part of main text, or part of a city abbreviation and NOT part of main text. e.g.

```
WASHINGTON D.C. Government officials on Monday...
(Government officials on Monday...)

NEW YORK U.S. Government's latest statement...
(U.S. Government's latest statement...)

NEW YORK A.B. Conglomerate's CEO said on Monday...
(A.B. Conglomerate's CEO said on Monday...)
```

This is where regex falls short since it can't use a lookup table or the likes to differentiate between the two cases. I can't just hard-code in `U.S.` as a special case after all (see third case).

Any ideas?

Comment: The only reason you can differentiate between ambiguous options is because you have frequently seen or heard the right option. Let your system count how often a prefix occurs and infer which phrases are most likely locations.

Comment: @Rhymoid That's sort of what I was planning to do, but that can only be done if I don't use regex. My question is, how do I build an algorithm like regex where I can incorporate something like that? Note, I have yet to take any algorithm courses (high school self taught)

Comment: You can (and probably should) use regex to isolate the longest possible prefix that could be a location. The rest is machine learning, though, and that's a very different kind of programming in my opinion.